Under what hypotheses is the primitive function bijective?
I am trying to determine under what assumptions the function
$$F:(0,\infty) \to (0,\infty),$$
defined by
$$F(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(s)ds$$
is a bijection. For injectivity, simply require that $f$ continuous in $(0, \infty)$ and $f(s)>0$ for $s>0$ (or $f(0)=0$ and $f$ increasing in $(0, \infty)$). I am finding it difficult to determine conditions for this function to be surjective.
My attempt was the following, if we leave the hypothesis that $f$ is increasing and that $f(0)=0$, $\lim_{t \to 0} F(t) = 0$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) = \infty$, therefore $F((0, \infty)) = (0, \infty)$. Is this correct or does it need additional hypotheses?
Thanks in advance!

By Intermediate Value Property of continuous functions $F$ is surjective if and only if $\int_0^{\infty} f(s)ds=\infty$ (or $\lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) = \infty$).  No additional hypothesis is needed.

A piecewise continuous $f\geq0$ may have multiple zeros as long as they are prevented from flattening the curve of $F,$ for example by requiring them to be isolated.
Such $F$ will be strictly increasing. The requirement $\lim_{t\to0}F(t)=0$ is satisfied iff $f$ is locally integrable near $0.$ This could be considered implicit in your definition of $F.$ The requirement $\lim_{t\to+\infty}F(t)=+\infty$ is in this context equivalent to requiring that $f$ not be globally integrable.
